# Everyplay on iOS 7 landscape

Tags: ios, ios7, cocos2d-iphone, orientation, everyplay

I've integrated Everyplay in my cocos2d v2.x game and sharing works fine on the iPad, but on the iPhone, when I tap "Share" from the Everyplay sharing modal, it crashes with the following message:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception `UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation`, reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and `shouldAutorotate` is returning `YES`'

Seems to be a problem in the Everyplay library. Any ideas for a workaround?

Comment: have you searched for this issue here? There are some workarounds for this, not specifically related to Everyplay but it being a general viewcontroller / info.plist / iOS 6+ setup issue there are at least pointers for sure.

Comment: I did search, but I couldn't tell if the problem is from Everyplay or from my code. I'd like to be sure of that before hacking and opening other doors.

Comment: check this link-take some idea from this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14266137/gamecenter-authentication-in-landscape-only-cocos2d-with-cclayer-for-ios-6

Comment: answer to a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370261/does-everyplay-support-landscape-in-ios6